# Unable to use variable when loading function via $this in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

When calling a function within a class I am using something like this:

```
protected $_mdl  = 'mdl_posts_latest';

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model($this->$_mdl);
}

public function index()
{
    $offset = 0;
    $limit = 5;
    $data['p_latest'] = $this->mdl_posts_latest->get_posts_latest($offset, $limit);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    .
```

and it is working.

The problem is when I ry something like:

```
$data['p_latest'] = $this->$this->$_mdl->get_posts_latest($offset, $limit);
```

It throws this error:

**Object of class  Posts_latest could not be converted to a string**

because, obviously, this code is wrong: `$this->$this->$_mdl->`

**So, my question is how can I define the name of my modeljust once at the top of my class and then use it as a variable within all calls for calling a function etc.**

Because right now I don't know how to do it so it would look like something:

```
$this->$model->get_something();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're loading the model, you should access the member variable like this, without the `$` preceding the member variable's name:

```
$this->load->model($this->_mdl);
```

You could look into PHP's [variable variables](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and [complex (curly) syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex). It would allow you do something like this, where you can use the value of the variable:

```
$this->{'_mdl'}->get_posts_latest($offset, $limit);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->load->model($_mdl);
```

instead of

```
$this->load->model($this->$_mdl);
```

then:

```
$data['p_latest'] = $this->$_mdl->get_posts_latest($offset, $limit);
```

or

```
$md1 = $this->$_md1;
$data['p_latest'] = $md1->get_posts_latest($offset, $limit);
```